# Help me remember a children's book set in the future

Tags: story-identification

Years ago, in the 2000s, someone handed me a novel about the journey of a girl in a post-apolyptic world where the sun was always covered by clouds, no plant life grew and the world was without color.

She was on some sort of journey to a temple and towards the end of the story she saw a plant grow in the barren earth, seeing color for the first time.

Anyone remember the title of this book or have any idea?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds a little like *Gathering Blue* from Lois Lowry's series of books set in the same universe as *The Giver*.

Comment: ...same universe? alternate universe?

Comment: @sq33G: Based on the Wikipedia summary, Jonas from *The Giver* shows up at the end of *Gathering Blue*. Reading a little further into the summary for *Gathering Blue*, this does not look like a good match. The character pretty clearly sees color all throughout the book, as does the rest of her village. The issue at hand is that no one knows how to dye something the color of blue. I quickly checked the summaries for *Messenger* and *Son*, the other two books of the Giver quartet and they do not match either.